# Rust write struct to the xls

Tags: rust, xlsxwriter, xls, rust-polars, rust-xlsxwriter

I found [rust_xlsxwriter](https://crates.io/crates/rust_xlsxwriter) to write some information into xls file. I need to write some struct (more than 10 fields in) into xls file. When I used python I could transform object into pandas Dataframe and write Dataframe into xls file, just in 2 lines. Maybe exists a way to do it in Rust without manually transform struct into vector of Strings.

I tried Polars, but I can't transform struct into dataframe, maybe this is my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context it is hard to say which is the best approach but you could use Serde serialization with the struct: [Working with Serde and rust_xlsxwriter](https://docs.rs/rust_xlsxwriter/latest/rust_xlsxwriter/serializer/index.html).